# to open another activity by clicking on an imageview in toolbar

Tags: java, android-studio

i put a setOnClickListener on an imageview that should normally open another activity but yet when i click on the icon of the imageview the app itself rather closeup. i dont no what causes that.please help

i put a `setOnClickListener` on the imageview that permit to open the next activtiy the code is the section in bold

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView lang, share, profileButton;
    TextView title;
    private EditText depart, arriver;
    private Button verifyButton;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        title = findViewById(R.id.title1);
        title.setText("EasyBooking");
        lang = findViewById(R.id.lang);
        share = findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

      ** this.profileButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileButton);

        profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), user_login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });**


        depart = findViewById(R.id.departurepoint);
        arriver = findViewById(R.id.arrivingpoint);
        verifyButton = findViewById(R.id.search);

        verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String departure = depart.getText().toString();
                String arrival = arriver.getText().toString();

                // Appeler une méthode pour ouvrir l'activité correspondante avec les noms de départ et d'arrivée
                openActivity(departure, arrival);
            }
        });

        //autocomplete texteview of departurepoint
        String[] Towns = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TownDeparture);

        AutoCompleteTextView editText = findViewById(R.id.departurepoint);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Towns);
        editText.setAdapter(adapter);

        //autocomplete texteview arrivingpoints
        String[] Town = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ArrivingTowns);
        AutoCompleteTextView editTexts = findViewById(R.id.arrivingpoint);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Towns);
        editTexts.setAdapter(adapter1);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.botton_nav_bar1);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.Idhome);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int itemId = item.getItemId();

                if (itemId == R.id.Idhome){
                    return true;
                } else if (itemId == R.id.Idagence) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Agence.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                } else if (itemId == R.id.Idticket) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ticket.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                }else if (itemId == R.id.Idsetting) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

// Ajouter un OnClickListener au TextView
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Créer un intent avec l'action ACTION_SEND
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                // Définir le type de contenu à partager (texte)
                intent.setType("text/plain");

                // Ajouter le texte de partage à l'intent
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lien de partage de l'application");

                // Démarrer l'activité de partage
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Partager via"));
            }
        });


       /* Ajouter un OnClickListener au TextView
        lang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Créer un objet Locale pour la langue anglaise
                Locale locale = new Locale("en");

                // Mettre à jour la configuration de localisation de l'application
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
                configuration.setLocale(locale);
                getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                // Redémarrer l'activité pour appliquer les changements de langue
                recreate();
            }
        });*/

    }

    private void openActivity(String departure, String arrival) {
        // Créez une intention pour ouvrir l'activité correspondante
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Douala__Bafoussam.class);
        intent.putExtra("departure", departure);
        intent.putExtra("arrival", arrival);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your XML code also in the above code? So that I can figure out that code

Answer (score 0):

I think you added ImageView inside your toolbar. Let's try the below code.

```
profileButton = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.profileButton); // call findViewById with toolbar.

profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), user_login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Let me know if not resolved.

Comment: No it doesn't works, the app closes up as i click on icon after execution

Comment: @KenneDany Add XML code also. I can't figure out how you designed your tab layout. Add XML code so that I can understand your design part